# ReactNavigation Error - Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

- "react-native": "^0.57.0",
- "react-navigation": "^3.0.0",
- "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.7",
- "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
- "redux": "^4.0.0",
- "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
- "reduxsauce": "0.7.0",
- "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.9",

Updating react-navigation to 3.0.0 in my React-Native app. I have followed the official docs here [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2018/11/17/react-navigation-3.0.html) and installed all the dependencies.

However cannot resolve this issue.

**AppNavigation.js**

```
const PrimaryNav = createStackNavigator({
HomeScreen: {
screen: MainTabNav,
}, {
mode: 'modal',
headerMode: 'none',
initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
navigationOptions: {
headerStyle: styles.header,
},
});

export default createAppContainer(PrimaryNav);
```

**ReduxNavigation.js**

```
import AppNavigation from './AppNavigation';
import { reduxifyNavigator, createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware } from 
'react-navigation-redux-helpers';

createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
'root',
state => state.nav,
);

const ReduxAppNavigator = reduxifyNavigator(AppNavigation, 'root');

render() {
const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;    
  <ReduxAppNavigator state={nav} dispatch={dispatch} />
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ nav: state.nav });
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation);
```

**navigation.js**

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';
import AppNavigation from '../navigation/AppNavigation';

export default (state, action) => {
Keyboard.dismiss();
const newState = AppNavigation.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
return newState || state;
};
```

**CreateStore.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import reduxThunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware } from 'react-navigation-redux- 
helpers';
import screenTrackingMiddleware from './screenTrackingMiddleware';

export default (rootReducer) => {
const middleware = [];
const enhancers = [];
const navigationMiddleware = createReactNavigationReduxMiddleware(
'root',
state => state.nav,
);

middleware.push(screenTrackingMiddleware);
middleware.push(navigationMiddleware);
middleware.push(reduxThunkMiddleware);
enhancers.push(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(...enhancers));
return {
 store,
 };
};
```

**RootContainer.js**

```
import ReduxNavigation from 'navigation/ReduxNavigation';

export default class RootContainer extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.applicationView}>
    <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />        
       <ReduxNavigation />            
  </View>
);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code? Looks like this is not found in the context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated the post with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding this plugin to .babelrc file.

[
   "@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types",
]

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you didn't link `react-native-gesture-handler`

Just type `react-native link` in your project dir.
And run again `react-native run-android`

Comment: It was already linked. Issue was with the "plugin-transform-flow-strip-types" plugin in .babelrc file